# How do I remove the first two characters from all cells in a selection using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, texttrimming

In order to make my macro work, I've added a double # onto the start of each cell using VBA -> ##*string*

However, I now need to remove the double hashtag for all cells in the selection, I'm using the below code to target all cells in my worksheet.

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

I would like to know if there is a way to first, highlight all of the data like I have above, then use something like a 'LEFT TRIM' formula to trim the first two characters of each cell in the selection.

Or if anyone has any other solutions, I would be open to them too.

Comment: `Range.Replace` might be useful.

Comment: As mentioned by @BigBen - with more detail `Range("A1:H100").Replace What:="##", Replacement:=""`

Comment: Are there "##" *not* at the start of the content, and which need to be kept?

Comment: substitute() or use right() with len()-2.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove (up to) the first two characters from cells within the selected area:

```
For Each cell In Application.Selection
    cell.Value = Right(cell.Value, Application.Max(0, Len(cell.Value) - 2))
Next cell
```